# C# Index of PictureBox in FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#

I have retrieve list of images from database and display in flowlayoutpanel.

```
int i = 1;
            byte[] imgData;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(localdb);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT image FROM Image", con);
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                imgData = (byte[])(rdr["image"]);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgData))
                {
                    System.Drawing.Image photo = Image.FromStream(ms);
                    pbName[i] = new PictureBox();
                    pbName[i].Image = photo;
                    pbName[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
                    pbName[i].Parent = this.flowLayoutPanel1;
                    pbName[i].Click += new EventHandler(butns_Click);
                    i++;
                }
            }
```

Since the picturebox is auto generate in the flowlayoutpanel. Anyone know how to find the index of the picturebox in the flowlayoutpanel by onclick the picturebox? Thank you.

```
private void butns_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the index from the collection of the parent control.
Be careful, index depends on all the controls placed in the collection.

```
private void butns_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
    int index = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.GetChildIndex(pictureBox);
}
```

Another way is to use the Tag property.

```
pbName[i].Tag = i; // puts index to tag
```

```
private void butns_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
    int index = (int)pictureBox.Tag;
}
```